# bootstrap clodufiy3.4 error occured

Tags: cloudify

I installed cloudify3.4 according to the cloudify DOCS. When I install the manager, and executed like this:

```
# cfy bootstrap --install-plugins -p openstack-manager-blueprint.yaml -i openstack-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml
```

an error occurred:

```
[ERROR] Workflow failed: Task failed 'fabric_plugin.tasks.run_script' -> Timed out trying to connect to 192.168.17.15 (tried 5 times)
```

I have already build a extern network 192.168.17.0/24 and I have already installed

```
cloudify_docker_plugin-1.3.2-py27-none-linux_x86_64-Ubuntu-trusty.wgn
cloudify_fabric_plugin-1.4.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn
cloudify_fabric_plugin-1.4.1-py27-none-linux_x86_64-redhat-Maipo.wgn
cloudify_host_pool_plugin-1.4-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn
cloudify_openstack_plugin-1.4-py27-none-linux_x86_64-redhat-Maipo.wgn
```

So, how to solve this error? Thank you to everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't connect the manager.
Please make sure that you have an ssh connection from the CLI to the manager.

Since you are bootstrapping an Openstack manager you should make sure to have an external IP if you are outside of Openstack or that the CLI is on the same network if you are on Openstack.